# Percentage breakdown

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, percentage

I wonder if anyone can assist on this product percentage breakdown challenge that I am having.

I have the following code to insert data into a table.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #ProductBreakdown
CREATE TABLE #ProductBreakdown
(
  Product VARCHAR(20)
  , [TotalSales] decimal(20, 2)
  , Percentage decimal(20, 2)
)
;

INSERT INTO #ProductBreakdown VALUES('Product A', 596.42, 0)
INSERT INTO #ProductBreakdown VALUES('Product A', 127.55, 0)
INSERT INTO #ProductBreakdown VALUES('Product A', 736.83, 0)
INSERT INTO #ProductBreakdown VALUES('Product B', 379.51, 0)
INSERT INTO #ProductBreakdown VALUES('Product B', 205.95, 0)
INSERT INTO #ProductBreakdown VALUES('Product C', 905.99, 0)
```

This SELECT query returns the correct percentage results, ie

```
SELECT PB.Product, PB.TotalSales, 
  [TotalSales] / SUM([TotalSales]) OVER(PARTITION BY Product) * 100 AS PercentageSales
FROM #ProductBreakdown PB
```

| Product | TotalSales | PercentageSales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Product A | 596.42 | 40.83 |
| Product A | 127.55 | 8.73 |
| Product A | 736.83 | 50.44 |
| Product B | 379.51 | 64.82 |
| Product B | 205.95 | 35.18 |
| Product C | 905.99 | 100.00 |

I would now like to commit those percentages into the table with an UPDATE statement. I am using the following statement

```
UPDATE #ProductBreakdown SET [Percentage] =
(SELECT 
  [TotalSales] / SUM([TotalSales]) OVER(PARTITION BY Product) * 100 AS PercentageSales
FROM #ProductBreakdown PB2 WHERE PB1.Product = PB2.Product AND PB1.TotalSales = PB2.TotalSales)
FROM #ProductBreakdown PB1

SELECT * FROM #ProductBreakdown
```

However, this returns 100% for each row.

Does anyone have any advice on what/where I'm going wrong?

Comment: If you're planning to store these values in a permanent table, don't. Storing aggregated values is generally a poor idea and you have to `UPDATE` many rows after a DML statement affects just 1 row. If this is meant to be in a table then rethink about using a `VIEW`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake you made was that you correlated the `TotalSales` column in the subquery as well, instead of just `Product`.

But you can update a CTE or derived table without joins or rescanning the base table

```sql
UPDATE pb
SET Percentage = pb.PercentageSales
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      pb.TotalSales / SUM(pb.TotalSales) OVER (PARTITION BY pb.Product) * 100 AS PercentageSales
    FROM #ProductBreakdown pb
) pb;
```

But I recommend you use a view for this instead anyway, as otherwise you would have to keep it in sync with a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can include your calculation in a CTE and simply update it:

```
with updateme as (
    select *,
      TotalSales / Sum(TotalSales) over(partition by Product) * 100 as PercentageSales
    from #ProductBreakdown 
)
update updateme set Percentage = PercentageSales;
```